# Parse PostGIS raw data

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.4

I have this raw text value extracted from Postgres geometry(point) type `0101000020E6100000FAFFEFE0FB444B40672BE61C924E3840`
I was wondering if there is any way to get the `lat`,`long` values from it without having to insert it into db again and using the `ST_X`, `ST_Y` functions!

Comment: Well-Known Binary is certainly decodable by many GIS tools, though first you'd need to convert hex string to binary.

Comment: SELECT ST_AsText('0101000020E6100000FAFFEFE0FB444B40672BE61C924E3840'); as what you have is already a binary geometry format.

Answer (score 3):

I cast the data as `geometry` and extract coordinates after :

```
SELECT ST_X(t1.geom) AS long, ST_Y(t1.geom) AS lat
FROM (SELECT '0101000020E6100000FAFFEFE0FB444B40672BE61C924E3840'::geometry AS geom) t1
;
```

Comment: Try running this: `SELECT ST_X(geom) AS long,
ST_Y(geom) AS lat
FROM (SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoHash('0101000020E6100000C924E3840') AS geom) t1`; and you will see what is wrong with your answer.

Comment: This would actually seem to be a bug in GeomFromGeoHash, as the geometry you are feeding to it in no way resembles a geohash and should return an error. Even `SELECT ST_X(geom) AS long,
ST_Y(geom) AS lat
FROM (SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoHash('01010000IamNotAGeohash') AS geom) t1`; returns  -179.999821438159  -84.1991949186074

Comment: @JohnPowell : I made the modification, hope that is the solution.

Comment: Yes, that works, although you don't even need the cast, as the string already represents the geometry, though there is nothing wrong with explicit casting.